# Is there a tool similar to fromelf for extracting binary images on Windows

Tags: windows, arm, elf

I wanted to integrate image extraction from an ELF system image based on address range, into a tool on windows. Is there any way i could do this on windows similar to using the fromelf tool from ARM tool-chain?

I would appreciate any pointers on this.

Thanks

Comment: elf files are fairly trivial to read.  You could write and your own utility in a half an hour or less.  or use objcopy to convert to intel hex or srecord and then 15 minutes later you have your own utility for reading that...

Comment: @dwelch Thanks, on doing bit searching about ELF format, i think it is indeed better to write a simple tool that does the job for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [objcopy](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objcopy.html) with [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or download a native windows binary from [MinGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Base/binutils).